# Liferay hook with spring cause deploy exception

Tags: spring, liferay, liferay-7

I'm migrating code of liferay hook from liferay version 7.1 to 7.4 and have problem with hook that also is using spring. When I try to deploy this hook with spring I get this exception in logs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: More than one auto deploy listener is available for C:\Sources\liferay-dxp-7.4.13.u43\tomcat-9.0.56\temp\20230127125211722PNNVWNES\listeners-hook.war: com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.HookAutoDeployListener, com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.PortletAutoDeployListener
at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.generator.internal.processor.WabProcessor._getAutoDeployListener(WabProcessor.java:413) ~[?:?]
```

It looks that liferay can't decide if this is a hook or a portlet. How to fix this?

Comment: What are you hooking? It's been a long time since I've looked at the ancient hook interfaces - typically any changes to the running systems are easier through OSGi.

Comment: Yep this code is like 10+ years old with some changes for compatibality with new liferay. Hook deploys and works fine without spring. Basically this hook has a bunch of listeners on article, layout changes. If my problem is not easily solvable I will probably think of rewriting code so it won't have to use spring.

Comment: If it's that old, I'd recommend to first look at the necessity, before porting the code: Very often, ancient customizations can now be replaced by configurations. If the hooks are (a) still necessary, and (b) implemented without spring, it's most likely simple to move them over to OSGi